# Why does my sculpt deform when adding another subdivison?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, subdivision-surface

I have a multires modifier with four subdivisions and everything is fine. Once I add a 5th one, points statrt sticking out of the head of my sculpted model. The don't go away until I reduce the preview to 0. Can anyone tell me why this is?[image]

Comment: Is there a mirror modifier involved? Is it before or after the subd mod?

Comment: There is a mirror modifier and I forgot that I should try to reorder them. I'll try that when I'm home later. Thank you!

Comment: I made a mistake. It's not subdivision. It's a multires with subdivisions. If I try to change the order, it says 'Cannot move beyond a non-deforming modifier'